# CompletionHandler for Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, completionhandler

I'm trying to return the responseJSON

```
static func getAllPersons(completionhandler:@escaping (Any) -> ()){
    let URL = baseURL + "api/person"
    Alamofire.request(URL).responseJSON {
        response in
        completionhandler(response.result.value as Any)
    }
}
```

But if i try to store the responseJSON in "res" it won't work:

```
var res: Any = ""
PersonResource.getAllPersons{ (result) in
    res = result
}
print(res)
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var res: Any = ""
PersonResource.getAllPersons{ (result) in
    res = result
    print(res)
}
```

Put print statement inside it will print the result

**Why ?**

PersonResource.getAllPersons is an asynchronous call so  print(res) gets executed even before completion block of PersonResource.getAllPersons executes and sets res

Comment: Thank you for answering
I understand that but I need to parse it to a list of persons and use it in multiple views so i wanted to store it. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @adrian-i : Write your parse code inside getAllPersons{ completion block. If you want the data to be shared among multiple views, create a singleton data source object (like an array in app delegate) and populate it here. You can reload views to show the data changes once you populate the array in multiple ways. You can write getter for data source and trigger notification indicating data source modification to other views and views can reload themselves :)

Comment: you mean kind of like a local repository?

Comment: @adrian-i : I am not really sure whats your idea of local repo is :) But if you want data to persist you can make use of core data in that case NSFetchedResultsController will let u know when data changes and if you dont want data to persist u can use array in singleton class (like app delegate or create ur own singleton class say AdrianDataSource and have a array as a property in it and access it across multiple VCs :)

Answer (score 2):

response.result.value is Optional, so try to return Any?. But this is better approach:

```
static func getAllPersons(completionhandler:@escaping ([String: Any]?, Error?) -> ()){
    let URL = baseURL + "api/person"
    Alamofire.request(URL).responseJSON {
        response in
        if let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
                completionhandler(json, nil)
        }
        else if let error = response.result.error as Error? {
                completionHandler(nil, error)
        }
    }
}
```